# RactiveJS - Advanced condition in conditionals structures

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, structure, ractivejs

In the documentation of RactiveJS, we just have condition in template to test if a variable is true or false... It's possible to make a little more details ?

A thing like `{{#var==1 && var2==2}}HTML CODE{{/var}}` ?

I have a lot of possibilities for a form and If I need to observe each variable for making conditions, it's really long & hardest...

If we can't, someone can give me an advice to find a good library to make data-binding =)

Edit:

After more tests, I discover this code is ok

`{{# var1 == '1' || var2 == '2'}}OK{{/}}`

But this code isn't

`{{# var1 == '1' && var2 == '2'}}OK{{/}}`

It's normal ?

Plunkr => http://plnkr.co/edit/09OwnGzcf9SgJUSEdlC5?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on the github issue, your ampersands are getting converted to `&amp;`. Use a `<script>` tag, not a `<form>`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ig0Z9u07gYnnGk0tP6Zy?p=preview

You can also add functions to the ractive instance and call those if you need to handle more complex logic:

```
{{# isOk(var1, var2) }} OK {{/}}
```

Or you can put your logic into your model (if it belongs there).

Comment: @martydpx , is this still available ? I mean, is `&` still being converted to ampersand ?

Comment: Ractive uses .innerHTML, so the browser will escape most tags (other than `<script>`). You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/cw3SX/

Comment: I have found one can use '&&' in the set command within a directive.  Therefore in you can set a boolean value upon a user action using the double ampersand, and then use the variable for other purposes within the page.